# getElementsByTagName returning null

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm getting tihs error:

> `Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null.`

Alert #1 pops up, alert #2 pops up, but obviously either the call to create `gvHeader` or the call to build headers fails and I never see alert #3.

I've also tried putting `#<%` before and after on `"dummyHeader"` and `"th"`.  I've tried `"TH"` as well.

Note, I'm trying to follow [this suggestion](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Scrollable-GridView-with-Fixed-Headers-and-Client-Side-Sorting-using-jQuery-in-ASP.Net.aspx). I have been unsuccessful in getting any help from the author or anyone else on that site.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CraigTest.aspx.cs"  Inherits="OfficeIntranet.Forms.Purchasing.CraigTest" %>  
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit,
     Version=4.1.51116.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" %>    

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">  
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $("#<%=gvOrderDetails.ClientID%>").tablesorter();  
        alert("Are we here 1?");  
        SetDefaultSortOrder();  
        alert("Are we here 4?");
    });

    function Sort(cell, sortOrder) {
        var sorting = [[cell.cellIndex, sortOrder]];
        $("#<%=gvOrderDetails.ClientID%>").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
        if (sortOrder == 0) {
            sortOrder = 1;
            cell.className = "sortDesc";
        }
        else {
            sortOrder = 0;
            cell.className = "sortAsc";
        }
        cell.setAttribute("onclick", "Sort(this, " + sortOrder + ")");
        cell.onclick = function () { Sort(this, sortOrder); };
        document.getElementById("container").scrollTop = 0;
    }

    function SetDefaultSortOrder() {
        var gvHeader = document.getElementById("dummyHeader");
        alert("Are we here 2?");
        var headers = gvHeader.getElementsByTagName("th");
        alert("Are we here 3?");
        for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            headers[i].setAttribute("onclick", "Sort(this, 1)");
            headers[i].onclick = function () { Sort(this, 1); };
            headers[i].className = "sortDesc";
        }
    }
</script>  

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderBody" runat="server">       
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelSPA" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">    
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="headerE" runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: auto;">
            <asp:Label ID="MainH" CssClass="headerText" runat="server">SPA Order Control</asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="headVersion" CssClass="textarea" runat="server"></asp:Label>                
        </div>
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelDetails" runat="server" Width="960px" Style="margin-left: 20px;" Visible="false">
            <div class="container" id="DetailsSection">                    
                <div>
                    <table class="tablesorter" id="dummyHeader" rules="all"; style="width:940px; height:25px; border-collapse:collapse">
                        <col style="width:78px" />
                        <col style="width:225px" />
                        <tr style="background-color: LightGrey; height:25px; font-weight:bold; border-width:1px; border-color:Gray"/>
                            <th scope="col">Item Code</th>
                            <th scope="col">Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div style="height:550px; width:942px; overflow:auto;">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvOrderDetails" runat="server" ShowHeader="false"
                            AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#FAFAFA" Width="924px" 
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="SortOrderDetails"
                            OnRowCommand="gvOrderDetails_RowCommand" EmptyDataText="No Data to Display"
                            DataKeyNames="STOREORDNUM" HeaderStyle-Height="22px" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="gvOrderDetails_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF"/>
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="LightGray" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Black" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="LightGray" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Gray"/>
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" Height="22px"/>
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ITMCD" HeaderText="Item Code" >
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="gvAlignCenter5pxR" Width="78px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DESC" HeaderText="Description" >
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="gvAlignLeft5pxR" Width="232px"/>
                                </asp:BoundField>
                            </Columns>                        
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                                
        </asp:Panel>          
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: The error doesn't mean it's returning null. The error means you're trying to call `getElementsByTagName` on a `null` value.

Comment: When the page is rendered , can you see an element on the page ( either view source or in the the browser dev tools ) with an `id="gvheader"` ?

Comment: `getElementById("dummyHeader")` is what is returning null. It is likely that the ID of the div you are trying to reference, has been modified due to master/content pages. Assign it a client ID or you could also use a unique class name and get it by that instead.